# MySQL : Composite primary key as foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, key, composite-primary-key

I try to do this into mysql :

Create a first table with A, B, C columns and a composite primary key on A and B.
Create a second table A, B, D, E columns with A, B, D as primary key and of course A, B referenced as a foreign from first table.

I use mysql workbench to creates columns, add keys and foreigns constraints, but when i try to apply i receive this error :

ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

The thing is that i don't know what exactly is wrong with my design.

Can you help me.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] and read [ask]. In particular show your DDL. Probably you don't realize that the referenced columns of a FK must be declared as PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL. (Here, AB in ABDE.) But "referenced as a foreign key" doesn't make sense. A FK does the referencing. And I expect you actually want ABDE(AB) REFERENCES ABC(AB). Please google a description of your problem (using "references" the right way), this is a faq.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have `(A, B)` pairs in the second table which do not have matches in your first table.

Run this:

```
select secondTable.A, secondTable.B
from secondTable
where not exists (select 1
                  from firstTable
                  where firstTable.A = secondTable.A and firstTable.B = secondTable.B);
```

With this query you will find `A`, `B` values in `secondTable` which do not match any records in `firstTable`.

To be able to create your `foreign key`, you will need to either remove those records from `secondTable` or `insert` their matches `into` `firstTable`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Actually i doesn't have any data into the second table because i am building it.

Comment: @RonanQuintin, do the types of the tables match? Can you give us some code?